# .htaccess and 301 redirect (dynamic pages)

Tags: .htaccess

in my website I have some pages structured in this way:

www.mysite.com/x/y.php?query=z

I wrote a rule in my .htaccess file that is rewriting the pages in this way:

www.mysite.com/x-y/z

Now, since I am getting some SEO problems with these urls I would like my .htaccess file to 301 redirect both urls (www.mysite.com/x/y.php?query=z and www.mysite.com/x-y/z) to something like this:

www.mysite.com/x-y/z.html

I can I do this? I am posting you my .htaccess rule:

```
AuthType Basic 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^/]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1/$2.php?titolo=$3 [L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Greetings from Italy

---

EDIT

Hi, as I wrote in my first post I need to 301 redirect some pages in my website. I have for example some pages like this:

www.mysite.com/dir/subdir/page.php?titolo=foo

which are now written like this (I am using the code I posted before):

www.mysite.com/dir/subdir-page/foo

Now I want to 301 redirect both www.mysite.com/dir/subdir/page.php?titolo=foo and www.mysite.com/dir/subdir-page/foo to this:

www.mysite.com/dir/subdir-page/foo.html

I put my htaccess in the "dir" folder. However the code you gave me did not work, I am sorry... since I am new to the htaccess I would appreciate very well your help.

Thanks in advance and best regards from Italy

Comment: when I wrote "I can I do this" I meant "HOW can I do this"... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir

## External 301 redirects
# /dir/subdir-page/foo to /dir/subdir-page/foo.html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [R=302,L]

# /dir/subdir/page.php?titolo=foo to /dir/subdir-page/foo.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php\?titolo=([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-%2/%3.html? [R=302,L,NC]

## Internal redirect
# /dir/subdir-page/foo.html to /dir/subdir/page.php?titolo=foo
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ $1/$2.php?titolo=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Pls provide some more details like which URL you tried that didn't work. And what error you got etc.

Comment: Hi, as I wrote in my first post I need to 301 redirect some pages in my website. I have for example some pages like this:

www.mysite.com/dir/subdir/page.php?titolo=foo

which are now written like this (I am using the code I posted before):

www.mysite.com/dir/subdir-page/foo

Now I want to 301 redirect both www.mysite.com/dir/subdir/page.php?titolo=foo and www.mysite.com/dir/subdir-page/foo to this:

www.mysite.com/dir/subdir-page/foo.html

I put my htaccess in the "dir" folder. However the code you gave me did not work, I am sorry... I would appreciate very well your help. Thanks

Comment: Alright I think I understand your problem better new. Pls check my updated answer now.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, you're awesome and now it's working great! However I would ask you (if you agree) where I can find some guides and tutorials to learn htaccess by myself, since I have other things to change but I would like to learn something rather than asking always for help. Thanks again!

Comment: Here is Apache reference manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html and a cheat sheet: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/ for all kind of examples. Even so many Q&A here on SO itself are of great help. Finally can you pls mark this answer as `Accepted` now.